# How to await an async function in the constructor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, async-await, webassembly

I'm writing a JS class, which calls `wasmFunc` in the constructor and saves its result to `this.val`. However, because `wasmFunc` is from a WebAssembly file, an async function `loadWasm` must be called before `wasmFunc` is callable. So I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
// index.js
async loadWasm() {
   // load wasm file
}

export class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    await loadWasm(); // Cannot work
    this.val = wasmFunc();
  }
}

export const myObj = new MyClass();
```

Ideally, this file `index.js` should export `myObj` that is ready for use. However, `await` cannot be used in the constructor.

Any solutions or thoughts?

Comment: You can't, `constructor`s can't be `async`. You could use `.then`, but then `val` isn't actually set by the time construction is "finished".

Comment: Create a new async method and call that from the constructor.

Comment: @Andy I've tried your suggestion but it's not working, because I need the result of the async function before other parts of the constructor run. I still cannot use await inside the constructor

Comment: @jonrsharpe Agree :) Instead of a promise, I do need a result that is ready to use

Comment: This is most likely a case of [the XY problem](http://www.xyproblem.info). You don't actually want to wait on anything in the constructor, nor can you (as has been stated repeatedly here), what you want is to do something that had lead you to try and solve this conundrum. You don't need to "load a WASM file" for every object you create, do you? I've implemented a JS-WASM "bridge" multiple times and there are good and less good ways to do it, reading a file that doesn't change, with every constructed object, can be wasteful. Also, what is `MyClass` for, exactly?

Comment: @amn Thanks for your comment and yes, I do not need to load the 'static' wasm file every time I construct a new object. Actually `MyClass` is a template for creating RSA key pairs, but since the logic for creating them has been written in the wasm file, I need to load the file once (and once only) using async `loadWasm`. I should move it out of the constructor. 
Btw, do you think call `await loadWasm()` right before `export const myObj` is a good idea?

Comment: Also, thanks for letting me know the concept of the XY problem. I'll try to avoid it in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Constructors must return an instance of the class being constructed
- Async functions must return a promise

Since a function can only do one of those things, a constructor function can't be async.

## Helper Function

You can use a helper function:

```
// index.js
async loadWasm() {
   // load wasm file
}

export class MyClass {
  constructor(wasm) {
    this.val = wasm;
  }
}

async function myClassFactory() {
    const wasm = await loadWasm();
    const instance = new MyClass(wasm);
    return instance;
}
```

You'll need to `await` the result of calling `myClassFactory()`.

## Store a promise in the object

You could also store a promise in the object you create:

```
// index.js
async loadWasm() {
   // load wasm file
}

export class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    const wasmPromise = loadWasm();
    this.val = wasmPromise;
  }

  async doSomethingWithValue() {
    const wasm = await this.val;
    console.log(wasm);
  }
}
```

Comment: The Helper function works, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

```
class MyClass {
    async constructor() {

    }
}
```

-> Uncaught SyntaxError: Class constructor may not be an async method

Edit: But you can this.

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(args) {
        this.arguments = args;
    };
    static async new(...args) {
        return new this(args);
    }
}
-> MyClass.new("test")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
export class MyClass {
    async loadWasm() {
        
    }

    async fn(){
        await this.loadWasm(); // Cannot work
        this.val = wasmFunc();
    }

  constructor() {
    this.fn()
  }
}

export const myObj = new MyClass();
```

try this. This should work for you.

Comment: This one may work in most cases, but I have to keep the `wasmFunc` inside the constructor for some reason :(